# Exchange Resource Scheduling Display Screen

Tags: outlook-2007, resource-management, scheduling

One of my clients is requesting an LCD screen outside of their conference room displaying the availability of that Exchange Room Resource.  Does anybody know of an easy way to do this?  I've found a few products that sync/integrate into Exchange for scheduling (Netsimplicity, PeopleCube, etc).  However, I'd like something that just interfaces with outlook and displays what the users have scheduled.  I mean, I could almost use Outlook if I could automatically refresh the display..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was briefly looking into this idea some time ago and came across [this page](http://cameronfuller.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!A231E4EB0417CB76!1509.entry).  We ultimately decided against pursuing the idea when the people asking about it decided it wasn't worth the cost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure these people would like to sell you something: http://www.visix.com/axistv.html

(Disclaimer: I found them via web search and have no idea whether or not they're good, bad, or indifferent.)